# How to resolve "An uncaught error was detected outside of a test" error in cypress

Tags: cypress, uncaught-exception

I am getting the "An uncaught error was detected outside of a test" issue with the following code but I am not sure why and how to resolve it? Any help would be great. Is there anything wrong with the import /export statement(s)?

**Utils.js**

```
import { eq } from "lodash"
import { fs } from "fs"
import { looksSame } from "looks-same"


export const comparePNGImages = (fileName) => {
    expect(fileName).to.be.a('string')

    cy.log("#### compareImages #### ");

    const img1 = fs.readFileSync("./cypress/fixtures/baseImage/" + fileName);
    const img2 = fs.readFileSync("./cypress/fixtures/currentImage/" + fileName);

    looksSame(img1, img2, function (error, { isEqual }) {
        // equal will be true, if images looks the same
        expect(isEqual).to.be(true);
    });
    return null;
}
```

**test.spec.js**

```
..... 

//define the file name 
var imageName = "SailingDirection.png";

//extract and save as a png file 
downloadPng(imageName)

//compare base vs current downloaded file
comparePNGImages(imageName)
 
.....
```

**plugins:**

```
..... 

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;
const pixelmatch = require('pixelmatch');
var looksSame = require('looks-same');

.....
```

**Error in Test Runner:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The two modules you are trying to use `fs` and `looks-same` cannot be used in the browser, only in Node.

Transfer the code to a task.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
import { fs } from "fs"
import { looksSame } from "looks-same"

const comparePNGImages = (fileName) => {
  const img1 = fs.readFileSync("./cypress/fixtures/baseImage/" + fileName);
  const img2 = fs.readFileSync("./cypress/fixtures/currentImage/" + fileName);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    looksSame(img1, img2, function (error, { isEqual }) {
      resolve(isEqual)
    })
  }}
}

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        comparePNGImages
      })
    },
  },
})
```

**In the test**

```js
const imageName = "SailingDirection.png";
downloadPng(imageName)
cy.task('comparePNGImages', imageName).should('eq', true)
```